# Passing an array of dictionary to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have an array of dictionary in python, and I want to pass it to my front end to use.

This is what my `pythonArrayObj` looks like:

```
pythonArrayObj =[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}, {"a":4,"b":5,"c":6}, {"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]
```

However, the problem is that when I do:

```
var test = {{ pythonArrayObj }};
```

It keeps giving an error due to the `"` quotation being converted into `&quot;` if I try and do `json.dumps(pythonArrayObj)` before passing it to my front-end, or `&#39;` if I don't.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've been stuck on it for the last few days and would really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Render it via a JSON serializer.

Comment: I believe this answer may give you what you need.
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033239/list-of-objects-to-json-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) to prevent translation of quote characters:

```
var test = {{ pythonArrayObj|safe }};
```

will result in

```
var test = [{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}, {'a': 7, 'c': 9, 'b': 8}]
```

in your HTML source.