# JSON serialize objects in Python in list / diconary

Tags: python, json

I am very new to Python and I have this rather large and complex data structure that is a list of dictionaries with lists of different objects.  When I try and convert this to JSON via json.dumps()  I get the standard

```
TypeError: <...> is not JSON serializable
```

I did some research,  and most of the answers point to a standard way of writing a custom encoder, which is fine, I can do that.  However,  I would like to be able to send my whole data structure to json.dumps() and not loop through everything, figure out what class it is, and build a json object from scratch.

Is there a way to add an encoder/decoder functions to the python class itself, so when I send a complex data structure to json.dumps,  the class itself knows what to do.

is there some magic **to_json**  or some way of adding a custom decoder to that class that gets called when the json.dumps runs into it?

Comment: Can you share the json data which you are providing.

Answer (score 1):

The custom encoder class handles that for you when you use `json.dumps(my_object, cls=MyCustomJsonEncoder)`. Your custom encoder would override the `default` method, which takes `self` and the object `o` to encode; test for the different types that need custom serialization, and pass the rest to the default with `super(MyCustomJsonEncoder, self).default(o)`.

A simple example that I often use is as follows:

```
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    Enhancement of base JSONEncoder, also handling these objects:
     * datetime.datetime
     * decimal.Decimal
     * uuid.UUID
    """

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            return float(o)
        elif isinstance(o, UUID):
            return str(o)
        elif isinstance(o, datetime):
            return {
                '__type__': 'datetime',
                '__value__': o.isoformat(),
            }
        return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(o)

    @staticmethod
    def dumps(obj):
        return json.dumps(obj, cls=JSONEncoder)
```

Comment: I am getting a AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'default'  I added some logging and it's choking on the type: 'stringmap'  what do I do for that?

Answer (score 1):

As Steven Wolfe stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41156709/7507867), you may want to look into [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/).  This library allows for encoding and decoding of complex Python object.

You could use it this way:

```
import jsonpickle

f = open(filename, 'w')
encoded_string = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
f.write(encoded_string)
f.close()
```

And to retrieve the data as Python object, simply use the `jsonpickle.decode(encoded_string)` method.  As the documentation says :

> The new object has the same type and data, but essentially is now a copy of the original.

I think that could work well for you.