# Convert json to python obj

Tags: python, json

I'd like to convert the parsed json data to python object.

here is my json format:

```
{
   "Input":{
      "filename":"abg.png",
      "fileSize":123456
   },
   "Output":{
      "filename":"img.png",
      "fileSize":1222,
      "Rect":[
         {
            "x":34,
            "y":51,
            "width":100,
            "height":100
         },
         {
            "x":14,
            "y":40,
            "width":4,
            "height":6
         }]
   }
}
```

I tried to create a class named Region

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height

    def __str__(self):
        return '{{"x"={1}, "y"={2}, "width"={3}, "height"={4}}'.format(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

def obj_creator(d):
    return Region(d['x'], d['y'], d['width'], d['height'])
```

I then tried to load the data into the object using the object_hook function:

```
for item in data['Output']['Rect']:
    region = json.loads(item, object_hook=obj_creator)
```

but i found that it got the error saying that

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

Actually I know how to assign the object to python object if my data is not nested. But I failed to do so with my nested json data. Any advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like what you are trying to manipulate is already a Python dictionary.

Did you try to print it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks as if your JSON is actually a dict.

You can create an instance of `Region` easily, since the dict properties and the instance attributes have the same name, by unpacking the dict `item` with two `**`:

```
regions = []
for item in data['Output']['Rect']:
    regions.append( Region(**item) )
for region in regions:
    print( region )
```

Output:

```
{"x"=34, "y"=51, "width"=100, "height"=100}
{"x"=14, "y"=40, "width"=4, "height"=6}
```

( after I have changed your `__str__` to: )

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{{"x"={}, "y"={}, "width"={}, "height"={}}}'.format(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

Comment: Great, thanks.
Just a reverse question. What if I got the regions list, and then I want to convert that directly to a json object. I used the method dumps, it works for individual region object, but not the whole list. Any direct way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: @user6539552 this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033239/list-of-objects-to-json-with-python